# OpenAPI extension for spring cloud contract compatibility with later version of spring-cloud-contract-gradle-plugin

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-contract

I am able to get OpenAPI extension (guru.springframework:spring-cloud-contract-oa3:2.1.2.0) to work spring cloud contract using gradle.

However, it works with up to org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-gradle-plugin:2.1.5.RELEASE. It does not work with later versions than 2.1.5.RELEASE.

Are there any plans to support later versions of spring-cloud-contract-gradle-plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems that that project is abandoned, you can use this fork instead https://github.com/mzielinski/spring-cloud-contract-oa3

To use it you can use jitpack.io https://jitpack.io/#mzielinski/spring-cloud-contract-oa3/v3.1.2.0

Comment: Thanks, can the artefacts be found in any maven repo? Is it compatible with java 1.8?

Comment: You can use jitpack.io https://jitpack.io/#mzielinski/spring-cloud-contract-oa3/v3.1.2.0